# Android Navigatoin Drawer (Menu) with scrollable footer

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

I want to implement a Navigation Drawer (left menu) in Android.

The menu should have a list of items at the top and a footer with two buttons on the bottom.

I have taken two approaches:

1) Add a footer to the list via

```
mDrawerList.addFooterView(footer);
```

With this solution the footer is like another item of the list. So if the list has few items, then the footer doesn't show in the bottom, in fact it is right below the last list item.

2) Apply a Relative Layout to the left component like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- The main content view -->
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <!-- The navigation drawer -->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:divider="@android:color/white"
      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
      android:background="@color/black"/>

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_margin="20dp">

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_iv_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:text="Test"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

However when not all the menu list items are shown the footer is above the list items, hidding the last items.

How can I achieve the right solution?

Do I have to use a ScrollView?

Thanks!

**Edited 1**

Using the 2nd approach and the android:layout_above in the left_drawer RelativeLayout I get something similar to the picture taken:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like there is an issue with your layout. You shouldn't need two `RelativeLayout`s.

Try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start">

<ListView
  android:id="@+id/left_drawer_list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
  android:divider="@android:color/white"
  android:dividerHeight="1dp"
  android:layout_above="@+id/dashboard_iv_profile_image"
  android:background="@color/black"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_iv_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:text="Test"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice the addition of layout_above in the `ListView` and moving the alignParentBottom to the `Button`.

Comment: The additional Relative Layout was because I have more than one button. I tried the android:layout_above property but when I change the orientation to landscape the footer is on top of the list, hidding the last items. I edited the question to show an image of the Pictures app from Google that has the same result, which isn't the one I expected, but with a header.

Comment: You still wouldn't need another RelativeLayout for two buttons. Play around with the layouts, you'll get it. So, without rotating the screen, my solution works. And now you have a new issue that your layout is changing after screen rotation?

Comment: @gonzalomelov Feel free to accept this as the answer if it helped you.